# ¿Cómo mostrar las coordenadas de un número entero ingresando solo el número?

Tags: c#, array

Estoy generando un array de 2 dimensiones (5x5) con valores aleatorios. Le pido al usuario que ingrese una coordenada, por ejemplo `1,2` y le muestro al usuario el valor de esas coordenadas. El código está abajo.

Pero ahora quiero agregar la opción inversa: permitirle al usuario que ingrese un valor y devolverle las coordenadas. ¿Cómo puedo mostrar las coordenadas de un número entero ingresando solo el número?

Este es el código de la primera parte, al que le quiero agregar la inversa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random(); 
            int[,] arr1 = new int[5, 5];
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y<5 ; y++ )
                    arr1[x, y] = r.Next(1,10);

            while (true )          
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 5 ; y++) {
                        Console.Write("{0} ", arr1[x, y]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.Write(" Ingrese la coordenada Y,X que desea consultar:     ");
                string Scoord = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Scoord.Length == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                string [] Acoord = Scoord.Split(',');
                int miX = int.Parse(Acoord[0]);
                int miY = int.Parse(Acoord[1]);

                Console.WriteLine("El Valor de las cordenadas ({0},{1}) es {2}",miX ,miY,arr1[miX -1  ,miY-1] );
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Presione enter para salir ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Luego del split de Scoord deberías verificar que los valores ingresados fueron más de uno, sino la asignación de miY resultará en un error intentando acceder a un elemento del arreglo más allá de los límites.

Comment: @Walter le agregué una descripción exhaustiva a tu pregunta. Por favor verificá si está bien y cualquier cosa comentá/revertí el cambio... Si está bien, por favor consideralo como ejemplo para futuras preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías comparar el valor que esta en las coordenadas y si es igual solo imprimes las mismas  algo así:

```html
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] MatrizNumeros = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
            Console.Write("Ingrese el valor del cual desea obtener las coordenadas{0}", Environment.NewLine);
            string Scoord = Console.ReadLine();
            Random r = new Random();
            int[,] arr1 = new int[5, 5]; for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) arr1[x, y] = r.Next(1, 10);
            Console.Write("La matriz resultante es:");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Environment.NewLine);
            for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                for(int K =0;K<5; K++)
                {
                    Console.Write( arr1[j, K]+" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", Environment.NewLine);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            var ValorBuscar = 0;
            if (Scoord.Length != 0)
            {
                ValorBuscar = Convert.ToInt32(Scoord);
            }
            for (int x = 0; x <5; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                {
                    if(arr1[x,y]== ValorBuscar)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Las coordenadas del valor ({0}) son ({1},{2})", ValorBuscar, x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para continuar...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```